# registry.npmjs.com cannot be reached

Tags: npm

It's first time I'm trying to use Actions in GitHub to load a package on npm.
My workflow gets error because of:

```
npm ERR! code E404
npm ERR! 404 Not Found - PUT https://registry.npmjs.org/github-custom-module - Not found
npm ERR! 404
```

I noticed that also trying to reach out by browse bar https://registry.npmjs.com/ or http://registry.npmjs.com/ and it responds something like:

```
{"db_name":"registry","engine":"couch_bt_engine","doc_count":2594600,"doc_del_count":334,"update_seq":12737068,"purge_seq":0,"compact_running":false,"sizes":{"active":52390186030,"external":150891609029,"file":52550172912},"disk_size":52550172912,"data_size":52390186030,"other":{"data_size":150891609029},"instance_start_time":"1640854262658073","disk_format_version":7,"committed_update_seq":12737068,"compacted_seq":12733464,"uuid":"d8db915449574fe1dbb729e34426a075"}
```

just wondering if someone got in trouble for the same reason and eventually how to fix it!

Thank you very much!

Comment: Is the npm package a private package ?

Comment: Yes it's in a private repo in GitHub.

Answer (score 1):

Since your npm package is in a private repo, your Github action may not have access to it. There are two approaches to solving this ->

#### The easy way

You can use a read only access token in the dependency list in the `package.json` file to install the packages. This will require changing the code base but it trivializes the CI part. Bear in mind that if the token expires or is deleted your builds will start failing.

#### The not so easy way

The other way is to again create an access token for the npm registry and then
adding it to the Github Secrets instead. So lets say we store it in
`NPM_TOKEN` then in your action file you could simply add this to the `env`

```yaml
steps:
  - run: |
      npm install
  - env:
      NPM_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.NPM_TOKEN }}
```

You also need to create a `.npmrc` file in the root of your project with a single line using the env variable to set the auth token.

```
//registry.npmjs.org/:_authToken=${NPM_TOKEN}
```

The npm cli will replace the value from the environment in so your secrets are safe !

Comment: Not super completed answer but, considered limited infos I explaied, I have to say that you got the point and helped me in reached out final solution. Just let me ask, please, if I want to update the library I successfully loaded (ex: I scripted new function...) how to do at this point?

Comment: You only need to run `npm i` to install all the dependencies in the package.json.

Also glad to help